# Undefined index php error but var_dump shows it is defines

Tags: php, arrays

I'm receiving this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/theclear/public_html/what/adminz/includes/func.inc.php on line 245
Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/theclear/public_html/what/adminz/includes/func.inc.php on line 246
Notice: Undefined index: state in /home/theclear/public_html/what/adminz/includes/func.inc.php on line 247
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/theclear/public_html/what/adminz/includes/func.inc.php on line 250
```

var_dump shows me:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(10) "killswitch" ["state"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(8) "readonly" ["state"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Function contents:

```
global $dbh;
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `1_bolean_settings`");
$stmt->execute();
while ($set = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
var_dump($set);
$col1 = $set['id'];
$col2 = $set['name'];
$col3 = $set['state'];
if ($col3 == '1') {$state = 'checked';}
else {$state = 'unchecked';}

echo '                               
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="'.$col1.'" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" '.$state.'>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div> ';

}
```

So if `var_dump($set);` is showing `["id"]=> string(1)` then why is `$set['id']` giving me an undefined index error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nested array. That means the data you seek is two levels deep:

```
$col1 = $set[0]['id'];
$col2 = $set[0]['name'];
$col3 = $set[0]['state'];
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I'm getting a nested array? I store and select the users from my members table in the same way and the arrays i get back for them are not nested

Comment: You have multiple results from your query. If you're only expecting one result to be returned you should limit your query to one result.

Comment: Although your suggestion solved the issue i found using a foreach loop instead of a while loop solved the problem with nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You var_dump shows that you have 2 results (so 2 arrays in your variable).

To access for example the first result, you have to use :

```
$col1 = $set[0]['id'];
```

Or you can use a loop, or use :

```
$stmt->fetch(...);
```

If you want to have only 1 row;